# How to Extract title, body and images from HTML with Apache tika parser

Tags: html, apache, html-parsing, apache-tika, extractor

I want to extract title, html body(plain text), image urls from HTML page, it it possible to use Apache Tika server to achive it?

Comment: How are you using Tika - app? server? java facade? parser directly? What format do you want the body in - html? plain text? What do you want to do with the images - save them? know where they are?

Comment: I want to just get body plain text, and image urls, don't need to download or save images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Apache Tika Server as-is, in a single step, you cannot get both the Body Plain Text and all `img` tag src URLs

You have a few choices available to you:

1. Firstly, ask the Tika Server for the plain text of the file. Then, a second time ask it for the normalised HTML + filter that client-side for `img` tags
2. Ask the Tika Server for the normalised HTML form, then grab out the `img` tag urls and plain text locally, likely with your own xhtml parser
3. Call the Tika java code directly, with a custom Content Handler, without using the Server.

For option #3, you'd want to largely follow the [fetch the body of the xhtml document example](http://tika.apache.org/1.9/examples.html#Parsing_to_XHTML), but throw away most of the tag information. You'd only care about `img` tags as tags, the rest you'd only pass through the inner characters